# "Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect" after entering OAuth code provided by the url

Tags: google-bigquery

I am new to BigQuery, I want to use bigquery through my java class. I have got the URL to authorize BigQuery Access and I have also got the permission code from the url, but when I use this permission code in my code I get following error.

Paste this URL into a web browser to authorize BigQuery Access:
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=488768089408.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&response_type=code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery&state
... and type the code you received here: 
4/-P5SeVJsfX8hcztKa_spJdqcP6XH.ovCNnaPn5t4SOl05ti8ZT3a9jBS6eQI
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:519)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:152)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:388)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:500)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.(HttpsClient.java:271)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:328)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:176)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:733)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:162)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:836)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:230)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:84)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:980)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:299)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest.execute(GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest.java:175)
    at com.ymsli.client.BigQueryJavaGettingStarted.exchangeCode(BigQueryJavaGettingStarted.java:250)
    at com.ymsli.client.BigQueryJavaGettingStarted.createAuthorizedClient(BigQueryJavaGettingStarted.java:110)
    at com.ymsli.client.BigQueryJavaGettingStarted.main(BigQueryJavaGettingStarted.java:68)

Please help me out.

Thanks in advance
Shri Kant

Answer (score 2):

This looks a lot like a potential firewall issue. Where is your application running? Does it have access to the network and HTTPS (port 443)?

Comment: Yes.. It was a firewall issue.. Its working fine now...Thank you so much.. :)